# How to read this for loop program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below for loop doesn't have x**2 in its body which is generally Tab indented in the next line then how this program is able to generate output as given below:

```
>>> squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

Output: `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]`

if so then how should i read this for loop?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but it's hard to find one because I know the term for this and you don't: this is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's equivalent to something like: `squares = []; for x in range(10): squares.append(x**2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for x in range(10)` simply means counting from 0-9.
the list comprehension `[x**2 for x in range(10)]` then takes every value and squares it, and saves it in the list.

Look at this link: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions